# How can I get access to the outer space of a closed path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-graphics, uibezierpath

Assuming that I have a closed path (either drawn by using UIBezierpath or Core Graphics) and I want to get access to the outer space of it to apply a visual effect to the view in which it has been drawn, How can I get access to that? I don't want to apply an effect to the path itself, I want to apply a color to everything that is outside the closed path.

Comment: you want to apply visual effect to the outer space or just to closed path ?

Comment: to the outer space, like a gradient from 1 to 0 starting from the outer edge of the path to the end of bounds of the uiview in which it has been drawn.

Comment: This is not the same question as you thing @matt It's about accessing the outer space of the closed area by a path, not the path itself.

Comment: It is actually just the same. The graph line is just part of a closed area in my example; using masking the gradient can appear outside it or inside it, as desired.